# Работа в Selenium web driver Action

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Создаю объект класса Action и как параметр передаю Driver,но почему-то на `Driver` выдаёт ошибку. `'Framework.Browser.Driver' is a 'field' but is used like a 'method'.`

```
Action builder = new Action(Driver);
```

`Driver` у меня задаётся так

```
public static IWebDriver Driver;
```

Comment: Может быть должно быть `Actions` ?

Comment: @Sv_t спасибо большое